# Need to intercept & redirect http requests because IP for site is invisible from test machine yet the webserver is accessible from an internal address

Tags: http, redirect, iis, silverlight, webserver

I need to access a website we have from a machine that isn't able to see the external IP of the webserver. All http requests are of the form http://a.b.c.d/sitelauncher/sitelauncher.aspx and fail to see the site since that IP is inaccessible, yet the webserver happens to be on the local network. How can I somehow intercept and replace so all requests are of the form http://192.168.x.y/sitelauncher/sitellauncher.aspx

Silverlight is required on the client side in case this helps although have no access to source.

Is there some tool available that would permit some kind of string replacement on each occasion an http request is made?

Have tried a thing called rinetd which complains because it can't bind to the original IP target:port (no surprise since it'll be invisible).

Any ideas folks?

Cheers
Iain

Comment: May I know why don't you call 192.168.x.y directly but call a.b.c.d?Most of time, we will create two binding, one for internal website and the other one for external website. Then only call the binding we want directly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. The site is called with 192.168.x.y directly which loads up the first page fine, however once we enter crendetials, say or something else the request that goes back is to the a.b.c.d address (we're using SilverLight at the client side which I've notived I'd not entered into the question). I'm not sure where it's getting the instruction from server side but certainly don't seme to have a way to change this. All I can think of is to try and intercept the request and replace with the IP we know will work.